# Shooting an arrow straight up, forces in play

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, energy-conservation, potential-energy

Okay, I'm a little confused with this question here.

Someone shoots an arrow straight into the air, we'll ignore friction, the arrow has a hardness of $1.0 kN/m^2$. The arrow itself weighs 12g. Before shooting it, he stretches the string by $\Delta s = 5.2cm$

So now, I have to calculate how high this arrow is shooting and explain what forces come into play and in which order. After that I should explain what the maximum speed is going to be after he stretches and shoots the thing.

I'm not expecting the whole solution obviously. I'm trying to teach myself physics (I'm 32), and I'm on a beginner level, this is part of a Danish self-teaching book. I'm not really sure where to start from here, how am I to interpret the stretch of the arrow here exactly? Can someone give me some pointers, or if it's easier to give me the solution, could you explain what each step does?

Comment: Welcome to PSE, and an upvote from me for your will! The answer should involve the Hook law and the conservation of energy laws (kinetic energy to potential energy and vice versa)

Comment: Just to get a few words straight. I changed stretches arrow to stretches string, that obvious enough.  By hardness, you mean tension, right? which is force, which is measured in Newtons . 1 Newton is defined as $1 kg × m/ s^{2}$ but you have  $1 kN/m^2$. So could you  please check the question as to the units, thanks . I don't understand hardness of arrow

Comment: Also if you read http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/1DKin/Lesson-6/Kinematic-Equations  and go through the pages there, all the concepts you need are explained  also https://www.wired.com/2014/12/much-energy-bow-goes-kinetic-energy-arrow/

Comment: What does your study book say about this situation? Are you teaching yourself, or are you asking for somebody to teach you?

Comment: @sammygerbil.  The OP clearly says he is teaching himself, and as a complete self study person myself, I can see his point when you may not have anybody else to turn to. With the greatest respect to you, compare this question with some of the 2 line **demands** we get for answers, its not the worst. It's  not a binary situation as how you phrase it, the OP wants guidance, not a complete answer. Maybe please  just ease up a bit on the genuine study people is all I am saying. Not every question has to be answered in a sharp way, (although some do for sure ), just ignore the ones you don't like.

Comment: @JohnRennie... jimmypaid, just an FYI, there's a [site](http://physics.qandaexchange.com/) that's just getting started that you might be interested in and, if I'm not mistaken, is looking for questions like yours.

Comment: @CountTo10 : The site policy is that questions such as this (ie exercises) should show some effort to solve the problem and ask about a conceptual difficulty. I don't see evidence of any effort here. If the OP is self-teaching, he must have some idea what is going on. If not, he is not learning and ought to go back to the last thing he understood.

Answer (score -1):

In this particular example (when simplified) there are 2 states. 1) when the arrow is drawn and 2) when the arrow is in flight.

In general, gravity will always be a force that needs to be accounted via the objects weight $$W = m*g$$

Now for the arrow string we can simplify that as a spring using the following equation: $$F_s = -k*x $$ where $x$ is the length of compression or expansion of the spring. So in your case that'd be the stretch of the spring. $k$ is the spring constant and the ($-$) sign simply enforces that a spring will resist the displacement applied to it (when you pull it the force will be to pull back for example).

So for 1) the forces are gravity and spring force.

Now for 2) you have a projectile which will have gravity, $W$ and now also drag $D$ (determining drag is outside the scope of this discussion.

As an aside, any object in powered flight will have its weight, drag, lift, and thrust. An arrow is just a object that produces no thrust or lift.